# Twilio's RAW HTTP POST request for status updates and message responses with all attribute names?

Tags: twilio

The documentation Twilio has on their website doesn't contain raw POST bodies, and it has conflicting sources on how the attributes are named/which attributes are included in the body.

Field names and their casing don't match:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message

1. Should I expect Message Resource type for all of their POST requests to our URLs(Status Updates and Message Responses) ?
2. Should I expect only the field names advertised on their Twilio's request page?
3. Do they provide all parameters or any additional parameters in their request not advertised on the documentation(Twilio's request)
4. I'm assuming they would also provide "MessageStatus" field in their POST requests, but I don't see it on all documentation pages.
5. The headers in their requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Of the two pieces of documentation you are referring to there, only one is about [the request Twilio makes to you when you receive an SMS message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters). The other is the [`Messages` resource of the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message).

So, in answer to your questions:

1) The attributes you receive are the ones described in the [request documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters). If you want to confirm this, then I recommend setting your webhook URL to a [Request Bin](http://requestb.in/) which is an easy way to inspect a webhook request like this. Alternatively, if you are [using ngrok to test webhooks locally, then check out the ngrok dashboard which also allows you to inspect (and replay) requests](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html).

2) Yes!

3) There are no extra parameters that I know of.

4) `MessageStatus` is not included. You can look it up using the Messages resource, but in my experience at the point of receiving the webhook the status is "receiving". Once you are done processing the webhook the status changes to "received".

5) The headers are mostly standard. There are extra ones for security, such as [the `X-Twilio-Signature` header](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#validating-requests). Again, I recommend inspecting a request with Request Bin or ngrok to fully understand the entire request.

Let me know if this helps at all.

**Edit**

The Content-Type header for `POST` requests from Twilio is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

In a message status callback, the parameters are all the [usual parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters) plus the [`MessageSid`, a `MessageStatus`, and if relevant an `ErrorCode`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional).

Comment: So the request parameters will be different when Twilio POSTS to my status update URL and POSTS a response to my URL.  Because, for status updates {delivered, sent, failed, etc}, there should be a MessageStatus field? I can try with the request bin, I was hoping to make sense of the documentation.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Also, since we are using POST method, I wanted to know whether Twilio uses 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in their request.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you were asking about StatusCallbacks too. I'll update my answer.